# How to convert html to word document which have <svg> tag inside html?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have html Page but it contains some charts so rendered html generates "svg" html tag i want whole page including pie chart and images should be exported to word document i tried with different libraries but chart is not exported help me.

Comment: you should post your existing code in case there's a problem with it. And explain which libraries you tried, and what was wrong with them. Otherwise people may well suggest the same thing to you.